# Did Protestant Founders lay their hands on their pastors like the Apostles in Book of Acts?

Tags: protestantism

In the Book of Acts the Apostles was seen laying their hands on their disciples in particular Matthias who replaced Judas Iscariot to be counted among the Apostles.

Among the Protestant founders like Luther, Zwingli, Calvin, Wesley, etc.Who among them is known to lay his hands on his pastors to transfer or give them a teaching authority? Or how does a Protestant pastors receive their teaching authority coming from Christ biblically?

Comment: My understanding is that the Anglicans (at least) ordained bishops by laying on of hands.  This was passed on through the Anglicans until modern times.  The reason I say this is that until recent decades the Roman Catholic Church recognized Anglican ordinations as being valid (though illicit).  Since the laying on of hands is an essential part of apostolic succession, it shows that they were doing this and had been doing it since they split from the Catholic church.  I believe Anglicans (and probably other Episcopalians) still do the laying on of hands.

Comment: @Tharpa Anglican ordinations are not recognized as valid in the eyes of the Catholic Church.

Comment: This site has so many protestant and I think some of the elite members who have a high score are protestant too. I think the credibility & integrity of their Pastors rest on how they can answer and prove their position biblically.

Comment: @KenGraham  I see now that you are correct on this.  However, I think that regarding the original question, Anglicans do perform the laying on of hands.  " This authority is specifically derived through the laying on of hands for the ordination of bishops in lineal sequence from the apostles"  https://web.archive.org/web/20170406221913/https://www.episcopalchurch.org/library/glossary/apostolic-succession#close